# Extract Month and actual year from a Month Period Format

Tags: python, pandas

Considering one dataframe with column which has values of the format " June 2021-22" or "January 2021-22", how do I parse Month and actual year from it?

This question is different because here we have values where year is i  a period format ( "2022-23") and not a straightforward year. Thus the actual value will depend on the month considered based on the financial year.

Eg, in this case value should be June 2021 and January 2022. Appreciate the help !

Comment: Simply `pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%B %Y')`

Comment: Why is January 2022 and not 2021?

Comment: `Thus the actual value will depend on the month considered based on the financial year.` - What month start financial year?

Comment: Financial year starts from April ( forgot to add it in the query) , thus 2021-22 starts from may 2021 and ends at April 2022.

Comment: @user8112228 - So my answer working well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%B %Y')
print (df)
              date         date1
0     June 2021-22     June 2021
1  January 2021-22  January 2021
```